# React Native Collision Detection

Tags: react-native

What's the recommended folder structure to create react-native packages such that root directory has the source of the component and a child folder "demo" has a demo package (referring to root component).

```
I tried:
my-component\
|_package.json (react-native: "^0.57.8")
|_demo\
  |_package.json (react-native: "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
   myComponent: "../" //referring to root folder
```

I thought to have demo folder run as expo but have root folder with only sources files. However, this causes collision detection even when I run npm start from within the demo folder. It complains of collision between root react-native and this one.

Maybe this isn't the best way to structure npm packages. What's a good way  to structure folder.